# HAProxy error: Some configuration options require full privileges, so global.uid cannot be changed

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, haproxy, ubuntu-14.04

After adding the line to `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` as [part of creating a transparent proxy](http://blog.loadbalancer.org/configure-haproxy-with-tproxy-kernel-for-full-transparent-proxy/),

```
    source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip
```

restarting haproxy starts giving an error

```
~# service haproxy reload
 * Reloading haproxy haproxy                                                     
       [ALERT]     230/153724 (1140) : [/usr/sbin/haproxy.main()] Some configuration options require full privileges, so global.uid cannot be changed.
```

I'm already running `service haproxy reload` as `root`. What else do we have to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Comment out following lines in your haproxy.cfg:

```
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
```

and restart haproxy.

Comment: you are a savior. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to fix this issue with privileges is to execute the below commands:

1. Fix haproxy capabilities

   ```
   setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin,cap_net_bind_service+eip /usr/sbin/haproxy
   ```
2. Fix `haproxy.pid` file rights

   ```
   touch /var/run/haproxy.pid; chown haproxy:haproxy /var/run/haproxy.pid
   ```
3. Comment out from `haproxy.conf`:

   ```
   User haproxy
   Group haproxy
   ```
4. Execute daemon as haproxy user:

   ```
   sudo -u haproxy /sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -D -q
   ```
5. Check haproxy process

   ```
   ps -ef | grep haproxy
   ```

   the result should be:

   ```
   haproxy  12800     1  0 фев12 ?     00:00:58 /sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -D -q
   ```
6. You  can put these commands in `rc.local` in order to start automatically with the system